# Pointer of Two dimensional array to function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Im kind of begginer in C++, just to programming in PHP and JAVA, I have problem to make a pointer to 2d array, then use this pointer in different function and cout values of [0] and [1].

There is part of my script.

```
    int size_dd = 5;
    int dd[size_dd][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size_dd; i ++)
    {
        dd[i][0] = 2 * i + 10;
        dd[i][1] = 4 * i + 20;
    }
```

I can read the dd[i][0] in main function but I cannot call them in function read(int* twodarray), as it returns int[int] and the 2nd parameter from array is lost.

Thing is that I need to make pointer to this array and call it in other function.

But the problem is when I handle *dd in to the function, it return that dd is int[int] value instead of int[int][int], how can I resolve it?

Comment: Show us a the main and the read function.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: And a pointer is not an array.

Comment: I ment pointer of an array, did not know where you reed that.

Comment: `int size_dd = 5;    int dd[size_dd][2];`  This is not valid C++.  You cannot declare an array using a runtime value as the number of entries.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is weird because if I cout the values in the main function without any references it is working fine, I cannot redeclare it to pointer.

Comment: @Potar Why do you need pointers?  Use `std::vector`.  Not only does it rid you of pointers in this context, your program becomes valid C++.  Also -- *There is part of my script.* -- you're writing a *program*, not a "script".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The teacher in our Uni require it in the exercise...

Comment: @Potar Does the teacher require you to use invalid C++ syntax?  Change that to `const int size_dd = 5;` to make it valid.  If `size_dd` can vary, then you have no choice but to use other means of creating a 2d array.  C++ does not have variable length arrays, so that syntax you're currently using is non-standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should have following signature:

```
void fooByPtr(int(*arr)[5][6]) {
  (*arr)[4][4] = 156;
}

// Call ex:
int dd[5][6];
fooByPtr(&dd);
```

You can also do it with reference and template:

```
void fooByRef(int (&arr)[5][6]) {
  arr[4][4] = 156;
}

template<int N, int M>
void fooByRefTempl(int(&arr)[N][M]) {
  arr[4][4] = 156;
}
```

Some other comments to your code (also the one from comment):

You can create arrays using constant values as sizes, so this is wrong:

```
    int size_dd = 5;
```

and should be:

```
    const int size_dd = 5;
```

in your fun_call you should dereference your array: `(*dwu_wymiar)` before indexing it.

finally, change `funCall(int(*dwu_wymiar)[][2],` to `int(*dwu_wymiar)[5][2]`, as in my example above.

Comment: @Potar I have updated answer, ... but it only should fix compile errors, wheether your code will work as expected....

Comment: It seems to like it is working now I will test my functions thanks!